# Replacing the Missing Values resulting from moving average at both ends

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

I applied `ma (order=13)` to one of the columns of the dataframe.  This obviously leaves first and last 6 values with NA.  All I wanted to do is to replace these NAs with median value of the `ma` series. I don't understand why the following does not work.

```
df$mavg <- ma(df$column1, order=13) 
df$mavg <- ifelse(df$mavg == NA, median(df$mavg, na.rm = TRUE), df$mavg)
```

There is no error message in the above. However, all values are NAs.

The follwoing seems to work though

```
xx <-  which (is.na(df$mavg))
df$mavg[xx] <- median(df$mavg, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Learning a bit of R with some python knowledge.

Comment: Try `ifelse(is.na(df$mavg), median(df$mavg, na.rm = TRUE), df$mavg)` because `NA == NA` will return `NA`.

Comment: To expand, the help file for logical operators says "Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA." So the comparison `anything==NA` will always return NA. The evaluation of `NA` in the first argument of `ifelse()` returns `NA`, so the resulting vector is all `NA`. Hence the `is.na()` function.

Comment: Thanks @markus, and gfgm for the explanation.  In IDL I used missing point indicator (mdi) to search and replace. IDL also has NaN which behaves like NA in R.